# Multi threading analysis techniques

Tags: multithreading, analysis

Does anyone know of any analysis techniques that can be used to design/debug thread locking and unlocking sequences? Essentially a technique (like a truth table) I can use to prove that my sequence of locks won't deadlock.

This is not the sort of problem that programming by trial and error works well in.

My particular problem is a read write lock - but I ask this in the general sense. I believe it would be a useful technique to learn if one exists.

I have tried a causal graph in which I have boxes and arrows that I can use to follow the flow of control and that has solved 80% of my problem. But I am still getting occasional deadlocks under stress testing when one thread sneaks though the "gap between instructions" if that makes any sense.

To summarize; what I need is some way of representing the problem so that I can formally analyze the overlap of mutex locks.

Comment: You'll probably want to use an automated tool, such as Promela and Spin, which I've seen recommended on Paul E. McKenney's _"Is Parallel Programming Hard, And, If So, What Can You Do About It?"_ book (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/people/paulmck/perfbook/perfbook.html).

Answer (score 3):

Bad news I'm afraid. There are no techniques that I know of that can "prove" that a system that uses locks to control access to shared memory. By "prove" I mean that you cannot demonstrate analytically that a program won't deadlock, livelock, etc.

The problem is that threads run asynchronously. As soon as you start having a sensible number of threads and shared resources, the number of possible sequences of events (e.g. locking/unlocking shared resources) is astronomically high and you cannot model / analyse each and every one of them.

For this reason Communicating Sequential Processes was developed by Tony Hoare, way back in 1978. It is a development of the Actor model which itself goes a long way to resolving the problem.

**Actor and CSP**

Briefly, in the Actor model data is not communicated via shared memory with a lock. Instead a copy is sent down a communications channel of some sort (e.g. a socket, or pipe) between two threads. This means that you're never locking memory. In effect all memory is private to threads, with copies of it being sent as and when required to other threads. It's a very 'object orientated' thing; private data (thread-owned memory), public interface (messages emitted and received on communications channels). It's also very scalable - pipes can become sockets, threads can become processes on other computers.

The CSP model is just like that, except that the communications channel won't accept a message unless the receiving end is ready to read it.

This addition is crucial - it means that a system design *can* be analysed algebraically. Indeed Tony Hoare formulated a process calculi for CSP. The Wikipedia page on CSP cites use of this to prove an eCommerce system's design.

So if one is developing a strict CSP system, it is possible to prove analytically that it cannot deadlock, etc.

**Real World Experience**

I've done many a CSP (or CSP-ish) system, and it's always been good. Instead of doing the maths I've used intuition to help me avoid problems. In effect CSP ensures that if I've gone and built a system that can deadlock, it will deadlock every time. So at least I find it in development, not 2 years later when some network link gets a bit busier than normal.

**Real World Options**

For Actor model programming there's a lot of options. ZeroMQ, nanomsg, Microsoft's .NET Data Flow library.

They're all pretty good, and with care you can make a system that'll be pretty good. I like ZeroMQ and nanomsg a lot - they make it trivial to split a bunch of threads up into separate processes on separate computers and you've not changed the architecture at all. If absolute performance isn't essential coupling these two up with, for example, Google Protocol Buffers makes for a really tidy system with huge options for incorporating different OSes, languages and systems into your design.

I suspect that MS's DataFlow library for .NET moves owner of references to the data around instead of copying it. That ought to make it pretty performant (though I've not actually tried it to see).

CSP is a bit harder to come by. You can nearly make ZeroMQ and DataFlow into CSP by setting message buffer lengths. Unfortunately you cannot set the buffer length to zero (which is what would make it CSP). MS's documentation even talks about the benefits to system robustness achieved by setting the queue length to 1.

You can synthesize CSP on top of Actor by having flows of synchronisation messages across the links. This is annoying to have to implement.

I've quite often spun up my own comms framework to get a CSP environment.

There's libraries for Java I think, don't know how actively developed they are.

However as you have existing code written around locked shared memory it'll be a tough job to adapt your code. So....

**Kernel Shark**

If you're on Linux and your kernel has FTRACE compiled in you can use Kernel Shark to see what has happened in your system. Similarly with DTRACE on Solaris, WindView on VxWorks, TATL on MCOS.

What you do is run your system until it stops, and then very quickly preserve the FTRACE log (it gets overwritten in a circular buffer by the OS). You can then see graphically what has happened (turn on Kernel Shark's process view), which may give clues as to what did what and when.

This helps you diagnose your application's deadlock, which may lead you towards getting things right, but ultimately you can never prove that it is correct this way. That doesn't stop you having a Eureka moment where you now know in your bones that you've got it right.

I know of no equivalent of FTRACE / Kernel shark for Windows.

Comment: So you are saying it's too hard as a  general concept - but if you restrict yourself to a provable strategy in the first place then it is possible to do significantly better than trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

For a broad range of multithreading tasks, we can draw a graph which reflects the order of locking of resources. If that graph has cycles, this means that deadlock is well possible. If there is no cycles, deadlock never occur.
For example, consider the Dining Philosophers task. If each philosopher takes left fork first, and then the right fork, then the graph of order of locking is a ring connecting all the forks. Deadlock is very possible in this situation. However, if one of philosophers changes his order, the ring become a line and deadlock would never occur. If all philosophers change their order and all would take right fork first, the graph again shapes a ring and deadlock is real.

Comment: the idea of closed loops in the graph is a good one. I hadn't thought of that. At the moment I have a graph - but hadn't thought of the loops - and I should have. So what you are saying is that any multiprocessing system can be represented by a causal graph and can only lock if there exists a closed loop in the graph. No so sure its an if the other way though.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock - it has an illustrative picture, and claims that circularity is a necessary condition.